# Float to left text in <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

I have this code in View

```css
  body .vr-list {
        padding: 0 20px !important;
        margin-top: 70px !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }
```

```html
  <ol class="vr-list" style="padding-left:540px;padding-top:10px;">
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Обзор существующих технологий  и применяемых api </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Общие понятия WebGL</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Интерактивный 3D rendering </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Основные идеи виртуальной реальности</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Интерактивность и FPS</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">FPS и частота обновления экрана </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Процессорный цикл</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Человеческий глаз против камеры </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Построение базовой 3D сцены</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Свет и rendering</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">История появления первой 3D модели</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Баланс цвета и пропорции соотношения цветов. Работа с цветовыми кругами Джонаса Иттена </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">WebGL и three.js </span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Основы UI/UX дизайна для 3D сайтов</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Oсновные ошибки при построении 3D сцен</span></li>
                <li style=" font-size: 1.6em;list-style: decimal-leading-zero;margin: 0 0 0 2em;"><span style="font-size: 0.95em;">Выпускной курсовой проект</span></li>

            </ol>
```

It shows list but text inside `<li>` tag is centered

Here is screen.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFAkz.png)

How I can make it on left not centered?

Comment: did you tried text-align:left!important; on <li>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `text-align` style to your li elements (Not just the main ul):

```
body .vr-list li {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text align is left when I run your codes. I think you used `.vr-list` class in other place. So, this style is override.
[your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdu46.png)

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason why you use inline styles and not css ?

Try using a more specific path , for example

`body #content ol.vr-list li { text-align:left}`

Something is clearly overwriting your code . I suggest you don't use !important . Either write a more specific path like i said before either you find the code that is causing the overwriting and change it

I think the you have some `text-aling:center!important` to the list on the left or to the entire body . That might cause the problem

Comment: if the answer worked for you . rate it as accepted . Glad i could help :D cheers